# How to make my program select a random color from C# opposed to a set color?

Tags: c#, random, colors, enumeration

So im making a program and it involves color values for 3 different.

I want to make the program pick a random color from the list of 4 for all 3 shapes, opposed to having a set color. Though I can't seem to figure it out.

```
enum color
{

    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    Black
}

//abstract class "Shape" which has 3 methods pretaining to attributes of the shape.
abstract class Shape
{
    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getPerimeter();
    public abstract color getColr();
}
//Triangle class which inherits the Shape methods
class Triangle : Shape
{
    public double s1;
    public double s2;
    public double s3;
    public color c = color.Red;
```

Comment: So what you want is each time you initialize a shape, for it to have one of the listed colors?

Answer (score 1):

```
public color c = color.Red;
```

What have you tried so far?

If you want the color of the child class to be random, you probably shouldn't assign it here. When you call your constructor and assign s1, s2, and s3 - that's when you're going to want to assign your new random color.

To pull a random from your enum:

```
Array colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(color)); //enum naming should be capitalized
Random random = new Random();
Color randomColor = (Color)colors.GetValue(random.Next(colors.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the program get a random integer value that would correspond to one of your colors.
Then, simply get the color from an array of the predetermined colors. Remember to make this a `protected` array in your initial abstract class.
You can get the color from the array in a constructor or in a protected function, its up to you.

**Colors array**

```
protected Color[] colors = new [] { Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow };
```

**Get random color from array**

```
Random r = new Random();
int color_code = r.Next(0,3);
c = colors[color_code];
```